# Null pointer exception for autowired class method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel and trying to build an api. It has three classes.

Class A - this  is for reading application.properties file as below

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="api")
public class A{

private String username;

public String getUsername(){
    return username
}
```

Class B - Apache Camel Route.

Class C - Bean class where class A is autowired.

```java
@Component
public class b extends RouteBuilder{
    @Autowired
    ClassC customC;

    public void configure{
        from("direct:start")
            .bean(customC)
            .to("log:first-timer")
    }
}

@Component
class C{
    @Autowired
    ClassA config;

    String username=config.getUsername();
}
```

Whenever IDE executes the api, it throws Null pointer exception in the line  `String username=config.getUsername();` .I have verified that spring boot is able to load application.properties.

I am not sure why calling method of autowired class is throwing null pointer exception.

Comment: Should @configuration be '@Configuration' with a C caps.. I am not sure if its a typo while posting, but besides that everything seems right.

Comment: have your tried constructor injection?

Comment: @Ferry,  I tried constructor injection  in class c "private ClassA config; public ClassC(ClassA config){ this.config=config;} String username=config.getUsername();" but it did not work. Am I doing constructor injection correctly?

Comment: assign username in the constructor, it would work. and if you use Spring 4 or lower, or Spring boot 1, you need to add `@Autowired` on your constructor. field injection is a bad practice btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `C` class.

```
@Component
class C{
    @Autowired
    A config;

    String username = config.gtUsername();
}
```

The sequence during Spring's initialization was like this:

1. Create an instance of `C`
   (by calling `new C()`)
   This constructor calls `username = config.gtUsername()`
   and fails with a `NullPointerException` because `config` is still `null`.
2. Process the `@Autowired`
   (initialize your `config` property)
   But of course it doesn't get this far because the exception already happened in step 1.

---

You can fix this problem by removing the initialization of your `username`
property from the constructor and instead put it into a separate method
(let's call it `init()`) and annotate it with `@PostConstruct`.
See also [Spring PostConstruct and PreDestroy Annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy).

```
@Component
class C{
    @Autowired
    A config;

    String username;
    
    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        username = config.getUsername();
    }
}
```

Then the sequence during Spring's initialition will be like this:

1. Create a `C` instance
   (by calling `new C()`)
2. Process the `@Autowired`.
   (This initializes your `config` property)
3. Call the `@PostConstruct`-annotated method.
   (This initializes your `username` property using the already initialized `config` property)

---

Another even simpler way to fix your problem, is to use constructor
injection (as @Ferry already suggested in his comment):

Instead of relying on the implicit default constructor,
you provide an `@Autowired`-annotated constructor which
can take an `A config` parameter.
Furthermore: By doing so, you will not need the
`A config` property anymore.

```
@Component
class C{ 
    String username;

    @Autowired
    C(A config) {
        username = config.getUsername();
    }
}
```

Then the sequence during Spring's initialization will be like this:

1. Process the `@Autowired`
   (create an instance of `C` by calling `new C(config)` where `config`
   is an `A` instance previously created during the autowiring process)
   This initializes your `username` property using the `config` received by the constructor.

Comment: Furthermore, as of [Spring Framework 4.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation), constructor injection no longer requires an `@Autowired` annotation on a constructor if the class defines only one constructor.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for detailed explanation.